# How to customize/remove the content that comes from the theme in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've installed the "NewsUp" Theme in my Wordpress website. I want to customize this, but not able to do this. I'm unable to change/remove the content (Recent comments, recent posts, etc) that comes from the theme. Actually, I need to change it as per my design requirements. Please guide me.
https://youtu.be/FSABUF878Zs

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWDfs.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can check for widgets under customizer, and if any is enabled, you can remove them.

This would help.

One more thing, that you can do is, you can go to Customize > Theme Options > Single Post and there, you can disable the settings such as

1. Enable Related Posts
2. Hide Comments and so on.

A short video that might be helpful to you :-
https://www.loom.com/share/0ddaad5ccdc6449596700c472b9851ee

Hope this helps.

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Surely, it was helpful. I'd have to go a long way to match its design with xd. Is there a way to change the colors of "recent posts" section and other sidebar sections?